# Automatic download of mp3 file

Tags: cmd

I need some help please.

I run a radio station which uses a downloadable news feed. At the moment I download it every hour manually.

I would like a script, preferably cmd, so nothing fancy needed to run it, that will download the file once an hour (using windows task scheduler) and put it in a certain folder. The download is not user/PW protected, it is free and copyrighted as such.

Can some kind soul please kick-start me?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a developer-for-hire service.  If you have an attempt at this and the code isn't working in some way, we'd be happy to help.  But I'm afraid Stack Overflow doesn't just accept software requirements and emit production software.

Comment: Hence the kick-start comment. I wasn't asking for you to do the work just give me a starting point. In future please read what you are complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget). A Windows version is available as part of the [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) package.

Using it is simple:

```
wget http://www.example.com/myfile.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **pure batch**, you might want to use:

1. [`CERTUTIL`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8485)

   ```
   certutil -urlcache -split -f <url>
   ```
2. `BITSADMIN`

   ```
   bitsadmin /transfer myDownloadJob /download /priority normal <url> <destination>
   ```

To automate tasks, use [`schtasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks):

```
schtasks /create /tn "MyTask" /sc hourly /mo 1 /tr "certutil -urlcache -split -f <url>"
```